TFT Transformer won't learn
I'm building up a project that utilizes a TFT Transformer for some predictions based on a dataset I created. Specifically, the dataset contains 2000 data points, that were collected in 15 hours by utilizing a DLT  (Distributed Ledger Technology) for block submission.
However, the model won't learn at all and I don't know why. Each epoch is always 0%. I tried to modify training parameters etc, but it is always 0%. However, what confuses me is that I tried to implement a similar manner following an LSTM approach, and it is able to learn. I thought that it might be a case of a small dataset size, so I also tried a synthetic one with 100000 data points, and it still didn't learn. I'd appreciate some guidance. Here is my code so far.
import numpy as np
import torch
from lightning.pytorch import Trainer
from pytorch_forecasting import TimeSeriesDataSet, TemporalFusionTransformer
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import MAE
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

df["submission_time_per_byte"] = df["submission_time"] / df["message_size"]
df["cpu_usage_per_byte"] = df["avg_cpu_usage"] / df["message_size"]

df["submission_time_per_byte"] = np.log1p(df["submission_time_per_byte"])
df["cpu_usage_per_byte"] = np.log1p(df["cpu_usage_per_byte"])

features_to_normalize = ["submission_time_per_byte", "cpu_usage_per_byte", "message_size", "block_count"]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df[features_to_normalize] = scaler.fit_transform(df[features_to_normalize])

df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={"index": "time_idx"}, inplace=True)

df["group_id"] = 0

max_encoder_length = 24   # how many past observations to use
max_prediction_length = 1 # predict one step ahead
training_cutoff = int(df["time_idx"].max() * 0.8)  

training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    df[lambda x: x.time_idx <= training_cutoff],
    time_idx="time_idx",
    target="submission_time_per_byte",
    group_ids=["group_id"],
    max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
    max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,
    time_varying_unknown_reals=["submission_time_per_byte", "cpu_usage_per_byte", "message_size", "block_count"],
)

validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, df[lambda x: x.time_idx > training_cutoff])

batch_size = 32
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=15)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=15)

tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate=1e-3,  
    hidden_size=16,      
    attention_head_size=4,  
    dropout=0.2,
    hidden_continuous_size=16,
    output_size=1,  
    loss=MAE(),
    logging_metrics=None,
    optimizer="adam",
)

trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=100, accelerator="gpu", devices=1, log_every_n_steps=1)
trainer.fit(tft, train_dataloaders=train_dataloader, val_dataloaders=val_dataloader)

torch.save([tft._hparams, tft.state_dict()], 'tft_model.pth')

actuals = torch.cat([y[0] for x, y in val_dataloader], dim=0)
predictions = tft.predict(val_dataloader)

print(predictions)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
